# Arduino Zero: Enable RTTI

Tags: arduino-zero

I need dynamic casts for my project, I'm getting:

```
error: 'dynamic_cast' not permitted with -fno-rtti
```

It appears that RTTI (run-time type information) is disabled with the `fno-rtti` compiler flag.

How do I change this?

Comment: We'll need to see your code in order to help.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It apparently is true that “RTTI (run-time type information) is disabled with the `fno-rtti` compiler flag”; however, looking at `compiler.c.flags` and `compiler.cpp.flags` in `platform.txt`, no `fno-rtti` compiler flag is set, suggesting that gcc sets it by default.

One way to turn off `fno-rtti` is adding a `-frtti` flag into the appropriate flags string in `platform.txt`.  As a side effect, this will affect all sketches subsequently compiled, rather than only those that need dynamic casts.

Note, on a microcontroller, a more-appropriate way to deal with the problem is getting rid of the need for dynamic casts, via function overloading.

*Edit 1:* On Linux, typical file paths to `platform.txt` are like `/opt/arduino-1.6.3/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt` or `/opt/arduino-1.8.0/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt`.  I don't know the location on OSX.  However, a command like `locate *avr/platform.txt` should reveal its location.  (If [`locate` is a new install on your system, first run `updatedb`](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/), which may take a while.)

Comment: Do you know where the platform.txt file is on OS X? Perfect answer, thanks!

Comment: @CodySmith, see Edit 1

Comment: This does not entirely solve the problem for those wishing to use rtti. This does not enable the linker to complete the compile of a simple sketch with dynamic_cast in it. What are the steps to get that aspect working. (I know there are people who say it shouldn’t be done, but I’m curious and have some ideas I’d like to test). I have drawn a blank as to how to complete this process. (Sorry this should have been a comment)
<windows dev platform>